# Testing Angular with Jasmine. What do module() and inject() do and how are they connected?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have written tests that include the following pattern, but I don't understand it.

```
describe("controllerName", function() {
    "use strict";

    beforeEach(function() {
        module("moduleName");

        inject(function(_serviceName_) {
            serviceName = _serviceName_;
        });
    });

    ...

});
```

What does calling the `module` function do? What does calling the `inject` function do? How does the `inject` function know to where it should inject the service?

It would make me happy if you can give a explanation that I can understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need the containing module to be loaded so that we could test it. `module` is a function provided by the `angular-mocks.js`. So calling it with a module name as a parameter loads that module.

`inject` is another method provided to us by `angular-mocks.js`. It gives us access to various dependencies declared in our file. Take the code you posted for instance, calling the inject function with a callback function gives you access to the dependencies your controller/service etc relies on. It's only inside that callback that you can assign those dependencies to certain variables and then use them inside your tests.

Since this needs to be done for each test i.e. the `it` block, the calls to `module` and `inject` functions are placed inside a `beforeEach` block as it is called before each `it` block.

Also since you called the `inject` function, it gave you access to the `serviceName` dependency which you would use somewhere in your test. We generally give a service name surrounded with `_`. That's just to differentiate them with the variables you use in your tests for those services. `$injector` strips down the leading and trailing `_` while resolving these names.

Hope this helps you understand the tests you write a little better.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing)